# Creating Email Sending Rules in WebForm in Drupal 7

Tags: webforms

Is it possible to create rules for sending automated emails within WebForm?

Some of the examples include (all emails are separate):-

- Send an email to user if he left a field to come back and fill it later.
- Send an email if he left certain part of the form.
- Send an email if a field is updated (or not updated).

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

See [webform_rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_rules):

> Did you ever want to react on webform submission using rules but
>   couldn't find the proper event? Webform Rules makes it possible to
>   catch webform submissions by rules and do whatever you'd like to do
>   with it (meaning: do whatever rules let you do with it).

It should let you perform most of the logic you've outlined here.

Comment: Thanks but I find it hard to understand that where it's located and how to use it? Any help?