# Send email only if a field has a certain value

Tags: 7, rules, webforms

I am using webform in Drupal 7 and have a case where I need to send an e-mail only if a certain select field has an option selected. I have installed Rules and Webform rules but am a bit stuck on how to get this going.

In my webform I have the field called type (which is nested in a fieldset called shipping). My 3 options in the field are Ground, Air, Ocean. What I would like to do is send an email (using Rules due to a pdf that is attached to the email) only if the option selected is Ground.

Is this possible with Drupal 7 and rules / webform rules?

Comment: in your rule, add a condition, entity has field, then you can access your field value and set your desired condition. iF you have several conditions, i recomendo you to use 'rules conditional module'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating Email Sending Rules in WebForm in Drupal 7](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/123506/creating-email-sending-rules-in-webform-in-drupal-7)

Answer (score 1):

I would use a technique similar to what is described in [my answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/191977/39516) to "[How can I compare data comparison with values submitted in a webform?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/191953/39516)". For short:

- Add an extra Rules Action to `Add a variable`, with a value assigned to it equal to your Webform data you want to use (and with an appropriate data type). You'd need 1 such variable for each Webform component for which you want to access its Webform data.
- In your subsequent Rules Actions you can refer to the value of these variables you just added (that's the clue!).